# Anyway to increase the quality of canvas capture stream using MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript

I was creating a JavaScript code for convert image to video using canvas I am using a canvas.captureStream and use MediaRecorder api for recording the stream but the recorded video quality is very poor there is anyway to increase the quality of the video

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?